# Can't connect to Adobe connect on php via curl

Tags: php, curl, adobe-connect

I want make request to login on Adobe Connect via curl

```
$ch = curl_init('https://emea2cps.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=login&login=nurgasemetey@gmail.com&password=D742455B61/');
curl_exec($ch);
$info= curl_getinfo($ch);
echo 'passed' . $info['total_time'] . ' secconds ' . $info['url'] . '------ and http-code'. $info['http_code'];
curl_close($ch);
```

But response is like this

```
 passed 0.078 seconds https://emea2cps.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=login&login=nurgasemetey@gmail.com&password=D742455B61/------ and http-code 0
```

I infer that it doesn't connect correctly but on browser on returns correctly. Where can be problem?

With regards

Comment: It probably requires a User-Agent header, too. Did you try specifying one? And, the URL is `https`, so you'll also need to set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to `0` `FALSE`.

Comment: sorry, I a bit new in this networking tools, can you expain what is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this param

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

### The code...

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('https://emea2cps.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=login&login=nurgasemetey@gmail.com&password=D742455B61/');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_exec($ch);
$info= curl_getinfo($ch);
echo 'passed' . $info['total_time'] . ' secconds ' . $info['url'] . '------ and http-code'. $info['http_code'];
curl_close($ch);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
passed5.922 secconds https://emea2cps.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=login&login=nurgasemetey@gmail.com&password=XXXXXX/------ and http-code200
```

Comment: it is good that you received such response. I added this parameter but nothing changed. Maybe problem is with my wampserver or such things?

Comment: Yeah btw do you have `curl` enabled ? Check your `phpinfo()` and see if `curl` is there.

Comment: Try `print curl_error($ch);` and see what's going wrong.

Comment: it responded like this : **Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to emea2cps.adobeconnect.com:443**

Comment: Can you try adding this `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);`

Comment: nothing changed. I guess problem in this : [link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=175433) I have 7.25.0 curl

Comment: Once Login is done , how to call another API ? DO i need to pass login authentication on each call ?